# Custom parquet schema with AwsWrangler

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet

I'm creating and uploading parquet files to AWS S3 using `awswrangler`.
The problem is that it auto generates the schema and since some fields can come in different formats (sometimes string, sometimes numeric), I get problems when trying to read the files.

I want to define a custom schema. From `awswrangler` documentation, I see that I can pass `dtype` as a parameter. But it says that it's for Athena/Glue.
I need to know if this argument also means that I'm passing schema of parquet files because I cannot test it locally (very difficult situation, long story)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to dump a `pandas.DataFrame` using `awswrangler.s3.to_parquet` method using a custom parquet Schema so that the schema is not direclty inferred from the pandas.DataFrame types.

Awswrangler allows to do that using the parameter `dtype` even if the documentation is only mentioning it for creating an Athena table based on the parquet file. Under the hood, Awswrangler performs a series of function calls ending up calling `def athena2pandas(dtype: str)` which converts your `dtype: Dict[str, str]` to compatible Pyarrow types before using `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter` to write the final parquet file.

Which means you have to use types (in string format) which appear in the function declaration (which are AThena column types): "tinyint", "smallint", "int", "integer", "bigint", "float", "real", "double", "boolean", "string", "char", "varchar", "timestamp", "timestamp with time zone", "datetime64", "date", "decimal", "binary", "varbinary".

```
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

// create an example pandas.DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"int_col": [1, 2, 3], "bool_col": [True, False, True], "str_col": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]})
// write paruqte file to S3 using dtype parameter to declare specific column types
wr.s3.to_parquet(df, "s3://YOUR_BUCKEY/FILE_KEY", dtype={"int_col": "int", "bool_col": "boolean", "str_col": "string"})
```

Note: A customer Pyarrow.Schema cannot be passed using `pyarrow_additional_kwargs`

Resources:

- https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.s3.to_parquet.html
- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/blob/main/awswrangler/s3/_write_parquet.py
- https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler/blob/5288032cf3e36de5d8ab4869ae57735974dac6cd/awswrangler/_data_types.py#L337